# how to count total as type in database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have table like this

[image]

I want to calculate the amount of data using the column, for example in the last column type "poc" totaling 3,so i want create query where result type "poc" result 3.
how to count total as type in database?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `group by`:

```
select type, count(*)
from t
group by type;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;

I think this can answer your question.